# How to measure stretching direction on chocolate-tablet boudins?

Tags: structural-geology, mapping

This has always bothered me during field mapping: A boudin with two stretching directions has the form of an M&M candy (or almond shape). What do I do to measure the two stretching directions if the surrounding rocks don't show any stretching lineations. Does anybody have experience with this?

Comment: I know nothing of the topic, but +1 for chocolate

Comment: @gerrit It get even funnier if you know that the word boudin means "sausage".

Comment: Can't you just measure the length of the major and minor axes of the ellipse? Or the 3 axes if that is important.

Comment: Have a look: [LINK](https://youtu.be/DX0lFcVp3bA). And for radial boudins here: [LINK](https://youtu.be/w6qcqm1_lUQ).

Answer (score 4):

If you can't get a macroscopic sense of lineation, try microscopic measurement  (thin sections along the supposed plane principal stresses) and transfer them in macro. [The Techniques of Modern Structural Geology: Strain Analyses Vol I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125769210) would be very useful for reference.